# Inkscape; transfer gradient names between documents

Tags: inkscape, gradient

For a webinterface i am designing icons in Inkscape. These icons all use the same colorsetting and gradient. Then, when designing the mockups i copy the the icons to a new document using copy + paste. Everything gets transfered well except for the name of the gradient.

When i want to change the color setting of the website, i need to change every single gradient or assign the 'default' to the icon. When having 20+ icons per mockup this is a time consuming task.

Is there a way to transfer the gradients of the icons between documents whithout loosing the name?
Or, is there a way to batch-replace gradients of the icons in the new document?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to transfer gradients across documents the way you explain.  But based on your question there may be a way to get this to work.  A couple of this things you can try

- Create your icons with the gradient and clone the remaining icons (select icon and Alt-D or Edit->Clone->Create clone) based on the original.  This way any change you make to original will work be propagated to the other clones.  This assumes that all your icons are based on the same object type.  A gradient for a rectangle will not transfer over to an ellipse.

  - Instead of copying and pasting the icons to a new document, make a copy of the document (Save As) and make changes to the new copy.  Save As does preserve gradients and if your icons were cloned you only need to alter the gradient on the master copy.